# My custom bootstrap tooltip style gets overriden when using data-container="body" attribute to work around overflow:hidden div element

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a custom bootstrap tooltip that my customer really likes. It works great on various elements.  I added it to a datafield of a gridview table, and it Worked (ed) great -- "until"  I added an `overflow:hidden` div to keep the gridview header row fixed.

Now the the tooltip gets occluded by this header row div.  I poked around and saw various workarounds -  the only one which kind of worked was to use `data-container="body"` (attribute) or various derivations of that using javascript which placed the tooltip on top of the header row div (when hovering the datafield of the first row in the gridview).

**The problem I have with `data-container="body"` or `{ container:'body' }`is that it overrides the custom style of the tooltip.**

I set the width to 500px and I use `!important`, ... but when I use `data-container="body"` the width becomes 200px and the background color changes.  I played around with `z-index:1000; position:relative;` in the css which helped the opacity which I have set to 1 but the width/background color still going to bootstrap default.

**What is a workaround for this so I can keep my custom tooltip style?**

Comment: Could you add some pictures to have a better idea or the affected code please

Comment: how do you upload/add a photo to a post on stackoverflow?  I can't see any tools here.

Comment: Anyway, the issue is that the custom popup tooltip gets clipped by the header row.  If I add the data-container="body" attribute in the markup, then my custom popup tooltip doesn't get clipped but I lose the custom styling (which the customer insists on).  How can I prevent the clipping of the popup and retain the custom style?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I came up with one -- non-programmatic workaround (which the client is sort of living with) and that is to add two blank rows to the beginning of the gridview and two more rows to the end of the gridview, and that way the rows with data content the popover tooltip doesn't get clipped now by the hidden div.  One other thing I tried was to make the overflow div visible.  This also worked to prevent clipping the tooltip, but I lost scrollability of the gridview.  Is there a workaround for that?